# An integrable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $a f(a) + b f(b) = 0$ when $ab = 1$.

Tags: integration, functions, indefinite-integrals

Consider an integrable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $a f(a) + b f(b) = 0$ when $ab = 1$.

Find the value of the following integration: $$\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx$$

I know how to do integration but how can I find the function $f(x)$ under the given condition .

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please provide context (what have your tried? Where does the question come from?) and use Mathjax for the math expressions

Comment: You don't need to solve $f$ to calculate the integral. Hint: split $(0,+\infty)$ into $(0,1] \cup [1,+\infty)$ and use change of variable $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$ on one of the interval.

Answer (score 2):

Split the integral into two:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx = \int_{0}^1f(x)dx + \int_{1}^\infty f(x)dx$$
Perform the variable substitution $x = \frac{1}{a}$ in the second one, then use the expression from the problem statement:
$$\frac{1}{a^2}f\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) = -f(a)$$